# MVC DropDownList Help - Select not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I am new to MVC and working on an already existing project.  I am simply trying to fill a dropdown to allow for changing of order.  When the page loads I need the dropdown selected value set.

The model on the view has only a few properties and then a list of type that gets iterated through to generate the data on the page.  These items are what contain the displayorder property

My question is concerning the order.  This view is used to change up the display order of the records on the page.  So there is a check to see what the largest displayorder is based on type and then selectlistitmes are added to the dropdown.  The dropdown fills fine but you can see the selected property gets set as well but this does not function when the page is rendered.  I always shows the first item.  I think the issue is here:  <%=Html.DropDownListFor(Function(x) x.Location, Options)%>

What I think i want up there is x.DisplayOrder (item contains the displayorder property) but that is not part of the model.  It is part of the list we are iterating through.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<td>
<%Dim Options As New List(Of SelectListItem)%>
<%For intDisplayOrder As Integer = 1 To Model.ReviewTypes(item.ReviewType)
Dim newSelectedItem As New SelectListItem
newSelectedItem.Text = intDisplayOrder.ToString()
newSelectedItem.Value = intDisplayOrder.ToString()

If intDisplayOrder = item.DisplayOrder Then
newSelectedItem.Selected = True

End If

Options.Add(newSelectedItem)
Next

%>

<%=Html.DropDownListFor(Function(x) x.Location, Options)%>

</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the property you are using to hold the dropdown value when the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put this part in your controller, and use formCollection.DisplayOrder to set the dropdownlist's selected item

```
<%Dim Options As New List(Of SelectListItem)%>
<%For intDisplayOrder As Integer = 1 To Model.ReviewTypes(item.ReviewType)
Dim newSelectedItem As New SelectListItem
newSelectedItem.Text = intDisplayOrder.ToString()
newSelectedItem.Value = intDisplayOrder.ToString()

If intDisplayOrder = item.DisplayOrder Then
newSelectedItem.Selected = True

End If

Options.Add(newSelectedItem)
Next

%>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.So if  i put this in the controller who do i get at options which is my list of selectlistitem?